# Записать обобщённый метод, выполняющий построчный вывод значений двумерного массива с заданным именем

Tags: c#, массивы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        double[,] twoD = new double[0, 0];
        Random random = new Random();
        int i, j;
        int size = random.Next(1, 5);
        int newSize = random.Next(1, 5);
        twoD = new double[size, newSize];
        Console.WriteLine("Двумерный массив. Строк: " + size + " .Столбцов:        " + newSize);
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
            {
                twoD[i, j] = System.Math.Round(random.NextDouble(), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
                Console.WriteLine(twoD[i, j]);
            }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Не очень понятна суть проблемы

Comment: Необходимо мой код переделать в обобщённый метод

Comment: Не понятно, зачем нужен обобщенный метод, если у Вас массив известного типа. Так же непонятно зачем вы инициализируете twoD в самом начале.

Comment: Обобщенный в каком плане? Что вы хотите обобщить и для чего?

Comment: @Sublihim, очевидно имеется ввиду `generic`

Comment: @Denis, для начала тебе надо _разделить_ заполнение массива и его вывод

Comment: @Grundy, да, первое, что приходит на ум - это дженерики, но тут нет ни одной причины их использовать. Может под обобщением автор понимает нечто другое?

Comment: По факту, необходимо просто отдельно сделать обобщённый метод и реализовать его. Мой код лишь делает построчный вывод значений двумерного массива

Comment: что-то типо этого необходимо сделать
http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1554945.html

Comment: @Sublihim, причина, потом подпихнуть туда массив интов например.

Comment: @Denis, что это за кусок кода? Всю необходимую информацию добавляй непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать его ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: @Grundy и оставить NextDouble?

Comment: @Sublihim, конечно нет :-) в задаче говорится только о выводе. Поэтому в комментарии выше, я написал автору, что надо разделить заполнение массива и его вывод :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам обобщенный метод, выводящий построчно все элементы двумерного массива.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            double[,] twoD = new double[0, 0];
            Random random = new Random();
            int i, j;
            int size = random.Next(1, 5);
            int newSize = random.Next(1, 5);
            twoD = new double[size, newSize];
            Console.WriteLine("Двумерный массив. Строк: " + size + " .Столбцов:        " + newSize);
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
                {
                    twoD[i, j] = System.Math.Round(random.NextDouble(), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
                    //Console.WriteLine(twoD[i, j]);
                }
            PrintArray(twoD);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        static void PrintArray<T> (T[,] arrayToPrint)
        {
            foreach (T a in arrayToPrint)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Поправил код так, чтобы вызывался метод без указания типа переменной в массиве.

Comment: а `ref`-то зачем?

Comment: @Grundy согласен, ни к чему. Это я просто в книжку заглянул по-быстрому, и там в примере с ref, и я не подумав воткнул. Спасибо за подсказку, поправил.